# How to access previous index route in nested routes using Link component from react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I am building a small react app, and I have implemented my routes like this:

```
import React, { lazy } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const App = lazy(() => import("./App"));
const Home = lazy(() => import("./Pages/Home"));
const Registro = lazy(() => import("./Pages/Dashboard"));
const Summary = lazy(() => import("./Pages/Summary"));
const Inventario = lazy(() => import("./Pages/Inventario"));
const Estadisticas = lazy(() => import("./Pages/Estadisticas"));
const Dashboard = lazy(() => import("./Pages/Dashboard"));

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />}>
              <Route index element={<Summary />} />
              <Route path="estadisticas" element={<Estadisticas />} />
              <Route path="inventario" element={<Inventario />} />
            </Route>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

As you can see I got some nested routes inside my Dashboard component, where I have set the Summary component to match by default using the index prop. My dashboard component is something like this:

```
import { Outlet, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Dashboard() {
 
  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/">Summary</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="estadisticas">Estadisticas</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="inventario">Inventario</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <Outlet/>
    </div>
  
  );
}
```

My problem comes when I try to access the Summary component from **Link to="/"** making use of the nav, instead of rendering the Summary component, it renders the Home component. I have also tried with **Link to="dashboard"**, but the url ends up being something like dashboard/dashboard, which does not work. **is there any way to access the Summary component from using Link to?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is that paths that start with a `"/"` character are considered to be absolute paths. This is why the "summary" link is linking all the way back to `"/"` instead of the parent path `"/dashboard"`.

## Solution

You can use `"."` as the target to the parent path, `"/dashboard"` in the case of user being on `"/dashboard/estadisticas"` or `"/dashboard/inventario"` paths.

Example:

```
function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to=".">Summary</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="estadisticas">Estadisticas</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="inventario">Inventario</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Sorry, at this point I'm unable to locate in the official docs this functionality, though there is a brief blurb regarding the use of `".."` to "remove one segment of the parent path". `".."` serves a similar purpose as `"."`. Note that `".."` would be used if it was one of `Estadisticas` or `Inventario` rendering a link to "go up a level".